# Was there a measurable effect on gas concentration on the Moon during the Apollo missions?

Tags: the-moon, apollo-program, vacuum

Gas was released by the Apollo Lunar Modules during depressurization of the cabin in preparation to an EVA.

Did this release of oxygen had a measurable effect despite the small amount of gas and the huge space of a very good vacuum around the landing spot?

Comment: the engine was more of a contribution. I have a factoid in my head, but can't substantiate it, that the lunar atmospheric density doubled taking about three months t return to normal.

Comment: @JCRM but during the descent there was nothing to measure a gas concentration at the landing spot. So maybe the ascent engine was more of a contribution.

Comment: Possibly related: [what does burnt Az50 smell like?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/10333/195) As far as I know, I'm the only person who takes the "who smelt it, dealt it" hypothesis seriously.

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't realise this was a question you already had an answer for.

Comment: @JCRM I appreciate other answers to my question, not only my own.

Comment: related: [When Chang'e-3 landed on the moon, did LADEE notice?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18848/12102)

Answer (score 4):

The ALSEP experiment of Apollo 14 measured such a release of oxygen before opening the hatch for the second and third time.

[image]

[image]